# change type-weightfrom css when parsing html to div

Tags: jquery, html, parsing, icenium

I'm parsing a html page with the following code:

```
function mealSearch() {
    $.get('http://www.season-hof.de/speisekarte.html', function(html){
       html = $(html.replace(/<img[^>]*>/g,"")).find("div.inhalt h2");
        $("#mealResults").html(html);
    });
}
```

The text on `.../speisekarte.html` is shown in **bold**.

Is it possible to parse the text in normal?

Comment: Does this work otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have some CSS set for #mealResults that is bold.  If not, set CSS for #mealResults to have font-weight:normal.

Comment: I set the font-weight: normal in my CSS. The parsed text stays bold

Comment: The parsed part send the bold with in h2. I set h2 to normal and it worked!